# Typescript is not compiled during build in VS13

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build, msbuild, typescript

I have `Project` and `TestProject` in my `VS13` solution. Currently I want to test my `TypeScript` part of the project but the problem is I am not able to get TypeScript files compiled during build.

TS files are compiled only after I save the file. I added this line

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

to my `.csproj` which worked for my standard project but does not work for my test project.

Is there any way how can I force typescript compilation during my project build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further googling I found interesting blog post [how to setup ts compilation on development and either on server environment](http://stevedrivendevelopment.com/2014/01/28/invoking-the-typescript-compiler-when-a-project-builds/). There is important note that the import section mentioned above **has to be after**

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

and it was not in my case. After fixing this, compilation started to work.